# TextAreaRow with a large text has a bug (Eureka)

Tags: ios, swift, eureka-forms

I found a UI bug (and a very strong slowdown) when I edit a large text in TextAreaRow. How can I fix it?

I deleted all my custom code (for example fonts and sizes) but the bug remained.

```
   [![fileprivate func noteRow() -> TextAreaRow {
        let placeholder = "example."
        let row = TextAreaRow() { \[weak self\] in
            $0.placeholder = placeholder
            $0.textAreaHeight = .dynamic(initialTextViewHeight: 38)
            guard self != nil else { return }
            $0.value = ""
        }
        row.cellUpdate { \[weak self\] (cell, row) in

        }
        return row
    }][1]][1]
```

I got it in logs but I do not use the MetalKit.

```
2017-05-11 08:51:11.424709+0400 example[5363:1263562] Nil drawable for layer <MetalLayer: 0x170484880>
2017-05-11 08:51:12.723664+0400 example[5363:1263562] Nil drawable for layer <MetalLayer: 0x170484880>
```

[image: ￼]

Comment: Which version of the libs and tools are you using?

Comment: @Efren I use the 3.0.0 version